# Richfaces action not called when clicked 2nd time

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a button like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Delete"
    reRender="parentForm"
    rendered="#{myBean.action == 'EDIT'}"
    action="#{myBean.someAction}"
    oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity != 'Error'})
    {Richfaces.hideModalPanel('thisPanel'); 
    javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('confirmationPanel')}" />
```

It works the first time user clicks on it. I'm able to set severity to Error in myBean.someAction. But if the user clicks on it a second time, myBean.someAction is not even called and oncomplete executes successfully. Why is this happening?

Comment: Which version of JSF? Also, is that button inside `parentForm`?

Comment: Richfaces 3.3, MyFaces 1.2. The button is inside parentForm.

Comment: are you sure that myBean.action value don't change after the first click ?

Comment: @faissalb If the value of myBean.action changes, then I shouldn't even see this button.

Comment: Maybe its not == 'edit' on restore view phase, this may have similar effect than what you're experiencing

Comment: @faissalb That was the issue! Thanks!

Comment: I've added a response to this post to let you accept to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its not == 'edit' on restore view phase, this may have similar effect than what you're experiencing